# Why does Optional<T> not implement Supplier<T>?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type, supplier

We all know that `Optional<T>` has a method `T get()`, so why does it not implement `Supplier<T>`?

If there happens to be no reason why, would it break any previous code if Oracle were to implement it into a future version of Java?

Comment: It raises a `NoSuchElementException` exception if it's empty; in its empty state it is not a `Supplier`.

Comment: You shouldn't use `Optional#get()` anyway, so it is actually a good thing it doesn't implement that interface.

Comment: @teppic But it's an unchecked exception, so what's the issue?

Comment: Would you clarify "you shouldn't use..."?

Comment: It's not a question of whether it could implement `Supplier`, but whether it should. I'd suggest that it would be hostile to clients to pass them a "Supplier" that might blow up.

Comment: @Zhro `Optional#get()` is unsafe and not better then the "usual" `null` check. Use other methods like `orElse(..)` instead. (further reading: https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-optional-replace-your-get-calls)

Comment: @Tom I made a new question to further query your suggestion. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46782731

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because they mean different things.

An `Optional<T>` is an argument that may or may not be provided, a return value that may or may not be provided, or a variable that may or may not be assigned a value.   If it has a value, you can use `.get()` to retrieve it.  `.get()` may throw an exception if **you** do something wrong, i.e., if you call it when the value is not present.

A `Supplier<T>` is a functional object that will provide a value (or null) on demand. Unlike an `Optional<T>`, it's reasonable for `Supplier.get()` to return a different value every time you call it.  If `Supplier.get()` throws an exception, it means that something went wrong in its implementation, not that the caller made a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

As [@MattTimmermans explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46782692/1553851), there's no logical reason for `Optional` to implement `Supplier`. However, Java's method references make it very easy to convert between interfaces sharing the same functional signature. Given an `Optional<T> o`, you can pass it to any method or variable expecting a `Supplier<T>` in the form of `o::get`.

Answer (score 2):

None of interfaces in java.util.function package have implementing classes (at least Java platform classes). I think this is because these interfaces were not designed for any other purposes but, as package description says, to provide target types for lambda expressions and method references.