# Can Optional ifPresent() be used in a larger expression to mitigate a call to get()?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

To avoid calling `get()` which can throw an exception:

```
if (a.isPresent())
   list.add(a.get());
```

I can replace this expression with:

```
a.ifPresent(list::add);
```

But what if I need to perform a larger expression like:

```
if (a.isPresent() && b && c)
   list.add(a.get());
```

Is it possible to still use a lambda form for this that mitigates a call to `get()`?

My use-case is to avoid `get()` entirely where possible to prevent a possible unchecked exception being missed.

Comment: I believe the [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46782957/1746118) performs the exact order as that of the question in terms of short-circuiting rather than the accepted one at this moment... and the short-circuiting does impact the amount of processing when performing multiple boolean operations.

Comment: Can we update the question to include `if (b && a.isPresent() && c)
   list.add(a.get());` to make it more interesting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My assumption is that you'd have to treat the other `boolean`s separately, but I could be wrong.

```
if (b && c) {
    a.ifPresent(list::add);
}
```

Actually, one weird solution could be:

```
a.filter(o -> b && c).ifPresent(list::add);
```

**NOTE**

- Make sure to look at shinjw's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46782957/7294647) for a third example!

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if my brain is functioning. Your first example is clear and is probably the way to do it. I'm going to leave this open for a bit to see if there are any other options. Using a filter is interesting but I can't think of a reason why you would want to do it that way over using a `if` statement.

Comment: @Zhro Some people want to always use functional whenever possible, doesn't matter if it makes sense or not.

Comment: too much of this and it just looks like line noise, even if you know what it does

Comment: you can do ifPresent on the next line for more readability. although i would definitely shy away from this approach

Comment: @shinjw Absolutely, and you could even split it up into multiple `filter` calls:  one for each `Predicate`

Comment: @JacobG. I can't tell if you're being ironic or serious.

Comment: @Oleg Mostly serious, as functional programming can become very messy very quickly; having one line per `Predicate` could help mitigate that.

Comment: `filter(o -> b && c)` ehh i disagree... why apply a filter if it has nothing to do with the object you're filtering on. that would never pass any sane people's code reviews

Comment: @shinjw Because we can >:)

Comment: ...Besides I would second the thought over short circuiting the conditions, this code would do check for `b` inspite of the fact that `a.isPresent()` is `false`.

Comment: @Zhro, if the predicates are expensive, then the `filter(...)` option would be preferable as they won't be called for an empty optional.

Comment: ***What***?! The predicate passed to `filter` is **not** evaluated, if the optional is empty.

Comment: @nullpointer: in case of `filter`, it does not. How should an optional evaluate a predicate for an object that does not exist? Passing `null`? That is exactly what the optional is supposed to prevent. Therefore, if the optional is empty, it does *not* evaluate `filter` predicates.

Comment: @Holger True that for this use case, when the check is specifically `ifPresent`, and the sequence has it as the first parameter. I was thinking much over [these lines though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46782731/can-optional-ifpresent-be-used-in-a-larger-expression-to-mitigate-a-call-to-ge/46782759?noredirect=1#comment80512824_46782731).. It would have been interesting to see the approach for that use case.

Comment: @nullpointer: that would be as easy as `if(b) a.filter(o -> c).ifPresent(list::add);`, but you shouldn’t evaluate boolean expressions for their side effect anyway. If `b` is an expression that can evaluate to an optional, you could also use `optionalCreateByB.flatMap(o -> a).filter(o -> c) .ifPresent(list::add);`…

Answer (score 9):

Adding one more to variation the previous answer:

```
a.ifPresent(obj -> { if (b && c) list.add(obj); });
```

If a is present. Check then add the unwrapped object

Comment: I'm imagining that he's looking to use the method reference (`lamda form?`) instead of writing out the lamda. but I definitely think this may be the optimal approach... considering that no additional checks are performed if the optional is empty.

Comment: Up-voting this as it is a good answer but in my use-case I wanted brevity and clarity as short circuit and order was not important, as mentioned. Jacob also kindly added a link to this answer at the end of his.

Comment: I also want to point out that this answer solves a problem where the expression must be evaluated in ascending order (a -> b -> c).